# How to get the selected item in JList to and use casting

Tags: java, swing, casting, jlist, getselection

In a part of my program, I have a `JList` that it has a list on locations, and I got an API that it should use an item from the `JList` and print out the weather of that location.  So now I can not do it, because I use

```
WeatherAPI chosen =  locList.getSelectedIndex();
```

but there is an error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to WeatherAPI.

This is the example of the API that works:

```
LinkedList<WeatherAPI> stations = FetchForecast.findStationsNearTo("cityname");
for (WeatherAPI station : stations) {
    System.out.println(station);
}
WeatherAPI firstMatch = stations.getFirst();
```

So I dont want to get the first option, i want to get the selected location by the user.  It's all about casting.
I also tried this which did not work:

```
WeatherAPI stations;
WeatherAPI firstMatch = stations.get(locList.getSelectedIndex());
```

I got the rest of the code, that it uses the "firstMatch, but it only uses it when its type is WeatherAPI.

Comment: Try .getSelectedValues()?

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to WeatherAPI

Comment: Crosspost: http://www.coderanch.com/t/608471/GUI/java/selected-item-JList-casting. Why are you wasting everybodies time posting a question that has already been answered?

Answer (score 5):

You have two choices.

If you're using Java 7 and you've created your `JList` and `ListModel` using the correct generics signature. Assuming something like...

```
JList<WeatherAPI> locList;
```

And a similar list model declaration, you could use

```
WeatherAPI chosen =  locList.getSelectedValue();
```

Otherwise you will need to cast the result

```
WeatherAPI chosen =  (WeatherAPI)locList.getSelectedValue();
```

Been a little old school, I'd typically check the result before the cast

```
Object result =  locList.getSelectedValue();
if (result instanceof WeatherAPI) {
    WeatherAPI chosen =  (WeatherAPI)result
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think the casting worked `WeatherAPI chosen =  (WeatherAPI)locList.getSelectedValue();` but in compiling it gives and error, and pointing to the line that the API uses **chosen**   `List<ForecastForOneDay> forecast
      = FetchWeatherForecast.getWeatherForecast(chosen);`

Comment: Btw here I have a help of someone who already has done this program, but i dont know what does that exactly mean: _Do you have a list of stations somewhere which you use to put information into your locList? If you do, when a user clicks something in the JList, you can use locList.getSelectedIndex() as the parameter for a stations.get call and the answer you get can be placed inside chosen._

Comment: You've declared your list to return use ForecastForOneDay object, how do you expect it to magically become a WeatherAPI object?

Comment: ermm I dont know :/ I just tried to follow the example of what API provided. program uses the firstMatch but I have to replace it with the selected item. So I really stuck now.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [getSelectedValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue%28%29):

```
WeatherAPI chosen =  locList.getSelectedValue();
```

Comment: Assuming that the OP is using Java 7 and the JList has been created with the correct generics signature

Comment: Didnt work, error: **Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to WeatherAPI** :( Here is how I made the JList.  `DefaultListModel<String> myList = new DefaultListModel<String>();
JList locList = new JList(myList);` @MadProgrammer my JList is working fine I can add and remove items. And Yes I use eclipse so it should be java 7 already.

Comment: Your list and list model MUST be able to contain WeatherAPI objects, otherwise the only result you can expect from it is a String

Comment: @AlexJj I wouldn't assume just because you're using Eclipse, you're automatically using Java 7 ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok so how can I make my model and list with weatherAPI? Should it be like `WeatherAPI Mymodel = new DefaultListModel<String>();`

Comment: Do it like this: `DefaultListModel<WeatherAPI> myList = new DefaultListModel<WeatherAPI>(); JList<WeatherAPI> locList = new JList<WeatherAPI>(myList);`

Comment: @WaleryStrauch Thank you for your comment.  Are you sure that the only way to fix it? because when I tried that it came up with many errors and wanted to change all strings to WeatherAPI in the whole program. :/

Comment: @AlexJj you either need to do it this way, or change the expectations of what is returned as a selected item to been a String object.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I guess I cant do that, because items in this list will be chosen from another list in another class which is String. So it goes so complicated it I change everything and maybe more problems would come up.